# Arrangements for a quiz

Tags: combinatorics

Say I have a multiple choice quiz of ten questions, each with four possible answers. How do I get the set of possible arrangements of those answers?

Comment: There are $4^{10}$ permutations, if that's what you mean. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product.

Comment: If your question is how many **possibilities** are there for the answer sheet of a multiple choice quiz of ten questions with each four possible answers to look like, this is *not* a "permutation."  This is an **arrangement**.  A permutation is traditionally defined as a bijective function from a set to itself, and can be visualized as a "rearrangement" of letters.  E.g. the six permutations of $\{a,b,c\}$ are visualized as $abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, cba$.  Not every counting question is a "permutation" question.

Comment: As for the content of your question, as Edward has pointed out, there will be $4^{10}$ possible answer sheets.  To describe the *set* of arrangements (*as opposed to simply the size of the set*), they can be seen as the set of functions with domain $\{\text{question}1,\text{question}2,\dots,\text{question}10\}$ and codomain $\{a,b,c,d\}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks, changed the terms in the question. Not sure what to tag with though. The rule of product does seem to be what I'm looking for, but is there an explanation of the algorithm anywhere? I want to know about the actual set, not the size. How would I use the domains to generate the set? (Apologies for being an idiot on a math help site, which I'm guessing that's what all the downvotes are for...)

Comment: The downvotes are likely a combination of a number of things including but not limited to: lack of context, no attempt shown, formatting, triviality of question, ...   As for the set itself, You know how you can count in decimal I hope:  $00, 01, 02, \dots, 09, 10, 11, \dots, 19, 20,\dots$.  You can do the same thing here, essentially in base four.  Letting the $i$'th character represent the answer to the $i$'th question, you have possible answer sheets $a\dots aa, a\dots ab, a\dots ac, a\dots ad, a\dots ba, a\dots bb,\dots, d\dots dc, d\dots dd$.  As for tag, "combinatorics" is pretty general

Comment: I've been away from the math world for so long that my attempt was limited to googling with the apparently wrong search term. Can't format with no equations involved and don't know how to give further context than the problem statement, but this is exactly what I was looking for so thanks again. Would you mind putting it as an answer so that I can accept it? Or should I just delete the question because this is an advanced math site only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of possible quizzes can be seen in a number of different ways.

One way of seeing it is as a cartesian product of sets:

$\{a,b,c,d\}\times \{a,b,c,d\}\times \dots \times \{a,b,c,d\} = \{a,b,c,d\}^{10}=\{(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{10})~:~x_i\in\{a,b,c,d\}\}$

where each outcome is described as a $10$-tuple, for example $(a,b,a,a,c,d,a,b,a,d)$ corresponds to the outcome where the answer to the first question is $a$, the answer to the second question is $b$, the answer to the third question is $a$, etc...

Another way to see it is as the set of all functions with domain $\{1,2,\dots,10\}$ and codomain $\{a,b,c,d\}$

$\{f~:~f~\text{is a function from}~\{1,2,\dots,10\}\to\{a,b,c,d\}\} = \{a,b,c,d\}^{\{1,2,\dots,10\}}$

However you choose to describe the set, one could choose to display each and every one via brute force methods if one was so inclined (though there are far too many to display here).  For example, by counting from $0000000000$ to $3333333333$ in base four: $0$'s represent answer $a$, $1$'s represent answer $b$, etc...

The size of the set is seen via the rule of product to be equal to $4^{10}$ via the following break down:

- pick the answer to question $1$ ($4$ options)
- pick the answer to question $2$ ($4$ options)
- pick the answer to question $3$ ($4$ options)
- $\vdots$
- pick the answer to question $10$ ($4$ options)

The total number of possible arrangements is then the product of the number of options at each step: $4\cdot 4\cdots 4 = 4^{10}$